# How to call rest api 600,000 times quickly and safely and insert 600,000 * n

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, insert, executorservice

my to do list

1. rest api get request about 600,000 times
   --- 600,000 = 2009~now * condition1 * condition2 * condition3 * condition4
2. process json data = 600,000 * n (make {flat json}... from {[json array]})
3. insert data in mariaDB (600,000 * n)

I created a request url using 4 nested loops(number of conditions) and received response data on an open connection.

However, some data caused a readtimeout (**con.setReadTimeout(1000 * 60) -- 1min**).

my method did not receive all the data for a day.

and insert didn't even try.

**I think I should multi-thread the to do list at once, right?**

Please advise how to quick and safe to call rest api and process the data and insert.

below my code.

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();
    List<Callable<String>> callables = null;
     for (String url : urlList) { //600,000 count
                callables.add(getRestapiData(url)); //call rest api 
            }

            try {
                executor.invokeAll(callables)
                        .stream()
                        .map(future -> {
                            try {
                                return future.get();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                            }
                        }).map(DataSummaryServiceLogic::getSettedKamisApi1DataList). //process ->return (600,000 * list.size) list
flatMap(Collection::stream). 
forEach(api1 -> provider.insertInitKamisApi1(api1)); //insertData
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jays Based on limited information shared by you ,you need to do proper exception handling. If 1 request is getting timed out of 600k , then it should not cause other request to fail. You can catch the request that is failing for whatever reason in logs/reprocess table etc. and retry later.

On making it multi threaded you can use a thread-pool and submit individual request to them to make it faster given you have sufficient cores to execute those extra thread.

Comment: thank you sir i added my code please check my code. thnak you :)

Comment: thank you reply. i solved myself. implements runnable method thank you :)